# COM, STA and multi-threading

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com

I have this legacy third-party COM DLL. I registered it to the registry and added RCW to my .NET/C# console application. The registry shows **Threading Model** for COM as **Apartment**. The entire purpose of my application is to concurrently submit multiple requests and receive responses to this COM server using multi-threading.

I am using SmartThreadPool for threads management, and now in each thread I'm creating new objects for COM lookup/request submission steps. However, still if I look at the COM SERVER LOG, the requests are being submitted/processed sequentially.

Where is the problem?

**So, I believe the problem lies in fact that COM is Apartment/STA configured**.
But my ultimate aim is to get it to work, so my questions,

1. Suppose all I have at my disposal is this STA COM DLL file, are there any-any-any workarounds I can make it process my requests in parallel?
2. Consider the fact, when I run two instances of my console application in parallel, the logs in ultimate server machine (with whom COM DLL actually connects and works) in fact show that requests from two instances are processed in parallel in two different sessions. So, the ultimate application is all geared to support parallel processing. (And I guess it's a childish question) Suppose I can get my hands on COM code, is it going to be easy stuff to make it support MTA?

[This is really getting too confusing and I'm getting nuts! Please note each of the threads is creating its own set of new objects from the COM DLL file for COMServer lookup, requesting, submitting, etc.]

#### Application code

```
public class start
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         StartProcessing();
    }

    private static void StartProcessing()
    {
        CoreProcessor pcr = new CoreProcessor();
        pcr.start();
    }
}

public class CoreProcessor
{
    public static ManualResetEvent IsAllDone;
    public static int NumberOfActiveThreads;
    private SmartThreadPool TPool = new SmartThreadPool();
    public void start()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> LstRequests = FileIO.GetAllRequestFileNames();
        NumberOfActiveThreads = LstRequests.Count();
        IsAllDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        foreach(var reqName in LstRequests)
        {
            ReqInfo req = new ReqInfo(){RequestPath = reqName;};
            TPool.QueueWorkItem(new WorkItemCallBack(req.ProcessRequest));
        }
        if(NumberOfActiveThreads  > 0)
            IsAllDone.WaitOne();
    }
}

public class ReqInfo
{
    public string RequestPath;
    public void ProcessRequest()
    {
         ABC_COM_Request req = new ABC_COM_XMLUTIL().CreateRequest();
         ABC_COM_Server svr = new ABC_COM_ServerLookup().lookup("serverhostname", 1099);
         ABC_COM_Response resp = svr.submit(req);
         if (InterLocked.Decrement(ref CoreProcessor.NumberOfActiveThreads) == 0)
                     CoreProcessor.IsAllDone.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Apartment" means that the COM server does not support threading.  All calls you make from worker threads will automatically be marshaled by COM to the thread that created the COM object to ensure it is used in a thread-safe manner.  You will not get concurrency.  There's no workaround for this, code that does not support threading cannot be made to support threading.  You already knew this from your previous questions.

Comment: Hans, very clear and precise as always, Thanks. But actually m using com for first time and so confused. I guess COM itself is executed in an unmanaged process and we use it through a proxy (RCW). So, when multiple threads use same COM, you mean our proxy is still sending parallel calls, un-managed COM synchronizing it?

Comment: Also, when u say "...All calls you make from worker threads will automatically be marshaled by COM to the thread that created the COM object...", I don't really understand; my worker threads are themselves creating new objects from COM dll

Comment: One important point, my client says they do have two clients, one in VC++ and another in JAVA, that do use same COM to submit/receive multiple requests/responses concurrently using multi-threading

Comment: @EagerToLearn: Your client seems to have a misunderstanding of how COM works; they might be submitting multiple calls from multiple threads (just like you are) but those calls are all serialized and called one at a time in the thread that the STA is on.  The COM subsystem does this automatically for you and you can't get around it (without seriously compromising the subsystem).

Comment: You can get concurrency by having many processes, each with one STA thread.  That may be what the VC++ and JAVA clients are doing.

Comment: @casperOne can you please reply for my updated question

Comment: @GTG: Perhaps, but it was phrased, the clients said they are "using the same COM", which I'm interpreting as the same instance.

Comment: @GTG - "You can get concurrency by having many processes, each with one STA thread." - also by having a single process with many STA threads.

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is the COM component and it is an STA component, then **there is nothing you can do to make an instance of that component service calls concurrently**.

However, that doesn't prevent you from instantiating *multiple instances of the component* and making the calls to multiple instances.  To this end you might want to consider using [COM+ object pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get your instances of the component that way.

Note that just because the service that the COM component is talking to is able to handle requests concurrently is an issue that is completely separate from the client's ability to handle calls to *it* concurrently.

Assuming you can get your hands on the code, it's impossible to say what would be required to get it to run in an MTA or free-threaded (the latter is preferable); we don't know the implementation details or the state that is stored (or what the API is like even).

If all the component is doing is sending requests and processing the responses without storing state, then it should be fairly easy, it's just a matter of switching the apartment.

However, there are two reasons which the component might be STA:

1) The component has a good deal of state and STA was a way to make sure that the state was not corrupted with concurrent calls; in this case, your job of making the component MTA/free-threaded will be difficult, as you'll have to safeguard everything and even then, you might not gain any benefits due to all the concurrency checks you might have to make (although you might find a way to convert the code to .NET code, in a manner which is easily thread-safe).

2) The component was written in VB6 or a language that doesn't support MTA/free-threaded components; in this case, it's impossible to change the apartment model and you'll have to either have multiple instances or do a conversion into .NET that is thread-safe.

Comment: ...doesn't prevent you from instantiating multiple instances of the component... What do you exactly mean by component? You see the COM dll has a variety of classes. Now, core thread of my application reads all request files from a folder, and then puts execution of each request on a new thread from Pool. Now each thread creates a NEW lookup class, creates COMrequest object, creates COMserver object and submits the request. So, each thread is already creating its own set of COM objects.

Comment: @EagerToLearn: I mean class instance.

Comment: Yes, so as i stated above, each thread is creating its own set of COM objects, but requests submitted by these thread don't reach in parallel

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create multiple STA threads, each with its own message loop (*), and each with its own instance of the apartment-threaded COM object.

You can set a thread's apartment state by calling [Thread.SetApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx).

(*) the message loop is needed if you need to marshal calls from another thread.

Comment: M using COM for the very first time, can you tell me in easy words. The COM third party DLL has many classes. Now i process each request on a separate thread from Pool. Each thread creates its own set of COMLookup, COMRequest, COMServer objects from COM DLL, but requests submitted through submit method on COMServer objects from different threads don't reach COM server application simultaneously.

Comment: Agree, you shoud be able to create several STA threads and each one can create a single instance of that COM component and interact with it.

Comment: You cannot use the system ThreadPool because they will not be STA threads.  Create your own threads and set them to STA.

Comment: The same thread that created the COM object must invoke the methods on that object.  Not having a code to look at, I'm guessing that is not the case.

Comment: @EagerToLearn, are you calling `SetApartmentState` on each of your threads before creating its COM objects, to make sure they are STA threads?